# Why isn't Heroku's Postgresql updating according to Django's models.py?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

Currently I'm running into issues with my models.py and Postgresql. The site is deployed on Heroku using Postgresql and the problem is models.py. Currently, I have models.py as a models.Charfield() and it works fine with sqlite, but when I deployed it to production, Postgresql still reports that it's a models.IntFied(). And because it's an integer field it won't allow for characters for some reason. 
Originally, I had it as a integerfield but decided to change to charfield, yet it still won't change to charfield. 
Solutions I've tried: resetting the database on heroku, deleting and recreating the database on heroku.

Any help is appreciated, 
Thanks

[image: This is the line for my Charfield in my models.py]

[image: This is the error for Django admin reporting an integer error.]

Comment: Make sure you ran `python manage.py makemigrations`

Answer (score 1):

To sync your models to your database relational schema, you have to run the command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

I normally follow the steps in this order:

1. Ensure that your database changes have all been committed with git add and commit commands
2. Reset the heroku database, Run
   {heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL}
3. Push your current changes to heroku with 
   {git push heroku master}
4. Launch the heroku terminal
   {heroku run bash}
5. On the heroku terminal run
   {python manage.py migrate}